# IIS and ISAPI-WSGI = very slow

Tags: python, django, iis, isapi, isapi-wsgi

I have loaded 2 Django apps on IIS using [isapi-wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/).

---

These are both server setups:

- **Windows Server 2003, IIS6 and SQL Server 2005**
- **Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS7.5 and SQL Server 2008**

The Django apps are completely different from each other.

---

They both take random periods of time for each requests **between 1 and 10 seconds**.

This is painfully slow compared to 100ms-500ms of an Apache+mod_wsgi setup, so there must be something wrong.

---

**Any ideas? Would really be great if I could fix this. :)**

---

## Solved!

**Do not use django-mssql use django-pyodbc instead!!**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Install another web server, like apache.

Seriously - IIS sucks on running python wsgi apps. There's not much you can do in that regard.

Comment: I wish I could... don't have a choice :(

Comment: @RadiantHex: You can run a python-only webserver in another port, and configure IIS as a reverse-proxy to forward the requests to this port. I think it would still be faster than using wsgi inside iis.

Comment: haha nice, well i don't have a choice if I want to deploy this project within this company... Accenture and IBM have severely locked down any alternatives.

Comment: @nosklo that sounds like an awesome idea... I could actually use that for one of my projects while the other one is unfortunately off-limits. Any wsgi to suggest, I think that gunicorn is only unix argh

Comment: @RadiantHex: If you have a choice of using python, maybe you can run a pure-python wsgi-enabled webserver like cherrypy's one, and then put django on it. Configure IIS to forward requests to it.

Comment: twisted.web.server.wsgi, cherrypy, paster