# django + IIS fastcgi, some problems

Tags: django, performance, iis, logging

I've successfully managed to setup django + IIS with fastcgi using this guide: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi
I've came across some problems:
1. I can't find a way to see error log - the python traceback, in apache with wsgi the traceback can be found in `error.log`, how can the same be done with IIS?

2. I've noticed that once in a while, after the site is "inactive" (no connections for a while), the next first request will be very slow. I've found related questions like this:
   [IIS and ISAPI-WSGI = very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193619/iis-and-isapi-wsgi-very-slow)
   But the accepted answer isn't going to be very useful to me, since I need to run it on IIS. /

Answer (score 1):

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi#route-handlers:
1. your WSGI_LOG location needs to be writable by the user your site runs under (the application pool user), so check the file permissions.

2: what's your IIS version? A slow application start-up is normal, but starting from IIS 7.5 you can enable **AlwaysRunning** as the application pool *Start Mode*, so the application pool is automatically started after a shut down. Do check your Idl Time-out (minutes) and Idle Time-out Action settings as well.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have a WSGI_LOG key, so I've defined it and set up permissions. But still this log doesn't contain error log (python traceback) like apache used too. Just lines like:  '2016-05-24 17:13:23.449000: wfastcgi.py will restart when files in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ are changed: .*((\.py)|(\.config))$'

Comment: My IIS ver is 7.5. I didn't understand where I enable the "AlwaysRunning"? I go to Application Pools-> DefaultAppPool, then?

Comment: (note: I may be mixing IIS versions and capabilities, I only have 8.5 available to me). Bring up the Advanced Settings of the application pool your app runs in. As Start Mode you _should_ have two options: OnDemand and AlwaysRunning

Comment: Under which category in these Advanced Settings you found it? The closest options I see are: Start automatically (under "General"), and Startup Time Limit (under "Process model").